# Elementor wordpress - the first sections is not visible in mobile

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, elementor

I was designing a wordpress page with elementor. The site is perfect in desktop. But while on mobile, the first section of the elementor is not displayed. Is there someway I can fix this with custom php code?

[image]

Comment: please share the website url, and a screenshot of the missing section.

Comment: @MohamedAliO.Ameur The link is https://sankarsubramanian.online/home. The missing section is the slideshow after the transparent header. Also the first section is visible only in landscape in mobile. Please help me out here

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by CSS code,
The following CSS code is causing the div height to be 1px which makes it invisible:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.elementor-section.elementor-section-height-full>.elementor-container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The expression

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
```

Applies the code only for screens with a higher width than 768 which makes it unsupported for mobiles.

To fix this you need to apply the following code to your custom CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
   .elementor-section.elementor-section-height-full>.elementor-container {
    min-height: 350px;
}
```

Give it a try and let me know.